# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=-1

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve `Timestamp` from this Firebase database, and set it as x-axis label. For the datapoint, it plots x value is index and y value is 100 everytime a child is detected.

[image]

The apps keeps crashing and returning: **`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=-1`**
I have 3 child in my nodes, but I can't figure out why my index keeps returning **-1**.

This database is for 1 user. Whenever I click on another client, the "userid" refers on another Firebase node and retrieve the fallstate. When I retrieve the first client data, it works just fine. When I click on the second one and try to retrieve the data, it won't work. Please tell me what did I do wrong.

Here's my code:

```
public class FallHistory extends AppCompatActivity{

String userid, fallstateValue, fallstateTimestamp;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseUser user;
DatabaseReference ref;
ArrayList<String> array9; //array untuk fallstate
ArrayList<String> array10; //array untuk fallstateTimeStamp
PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint> series ;
int x=0;
int i = 1;
String[] xLabels ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fall_history);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    final GraphView graph = (GraphView)findViewById(R.id.graphFall);
    series = new PointsGraphSeries<>();
    final StaticLabelsFormatter staticLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graph);
    graph.addSeries(series);
    Viewport vp = graph.getViewport();
    vp.setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    vp.setMinX(0);
    vp.setMaxX(3); //yg ditunjukin max berapa
    vp.setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    vp.setMinY(1);
    vp.setMaxY(200); //yg ditunjukin max berapa
    graph.getViewport().setScrollable(true); // enables horizontal scrolling
    //graph.getViewport().setScrollableY(true); // enables vertical scrolling
    //graph.getViewport().setScalable(true); // enables horizontal zooming and scrolling
    //graph.getViewport().setScalableY(true); // enables vertical zooming and scrolling

    array9 = new ArrayList<>(); //array untuk fallstate
    array10 = new ArrayList<>(); //array untuk fallstate timeStamp

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent!=null)
    {
        userid = intent.getStringExtra("userid");
    }

 ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid);
    ref.child("fallstate").child("nilaifallstate").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fallstateValue = dataSnapshot.child("fallstate").getValue(String.class);
            fallstateTimestamp = dataSnapshot.child("Timestamp").getValue(String.class);
            Log.i("fallstate value", "fallstate value " + fallstateValue);
            Log.i("fall timestamp", "fall timestamp " + fallstateTimestamp);
            array9.add(fallstateValue);
            array10.add(fallstateTimestamp);
            x = x + 1;
            DataPoint point = new DataPoint(x, 100);
            series.appendData(point, true, 1000);

            xLabels = new String[array10.size()];
            array10.toArray(xLabels);


            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHumanRounding(true);
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsAngle(90);

            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DefaultLabelFormatter()
            {
                @Override
                public String formatLabel(double value, boolean isValueX)
                {
                    if (isValueX)
                    {
                        return xLabels[(int) value];
                    }
                    return super.formatLabel(value,isValueX);
                }
            });

            Log.i("xlabels", "xlabels " + xLabels);

        }
```

Please tell me what did I do wrong.

Comment: Keep in mind this error could be caused by accessing to an `List` from different threads at the same time, because the `List` is not thread safe. Do you have more than one thread? Also would be great to post more code and the full exception.

Comment: I have updated the code, but I don't know what you mean by accessing from multiple thread. What did I do wrong? Thank you by the way!!

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=-1
```

Means that you have 3 elements in your array and you are trying to get an element from an incorrect index. Those three element are placed at index 0, 1 and 2 becuase in Java, array indexes start with **`0`**!

Please also note that `onChildAdded` method is asynchronous. When using the following line of code:

```
Log.i("xlabels", "xlabels " + xLabels);
```

Your array will always be empty.

Comment: But I really dont understand the index part. Where did i set the index to be -1?

Comment: Also, when I try to access user with 2 fall data, I get  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=-2

Then I try to access user with 1 fall data, I get :
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=-3

Comment: Yes and this is because you are trying again to get an element from a wrong index. I assume you are getting that error at this line of code `return super.formatLabel(value,isValueX)`, right? So try to change the way you are accesing the array passing correct indexes. Please see also the note in my updated answer.

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Have you solved the issue?